# EggPlant Script Hanging on If-Statement

Tags: eggplant

I have a simple script to open the Apple Maps app and then click the "Allow" option that appears if you haven't allowed the app your location in Settings.

```
Click "AppIcon_Maps"
If ImageFound(text:"Allow") then click it
PressHomeButton
```

However, when I run my script, Eggplant clicks on the Apple Maps icon and then never completes the if-statement. In fact, while running the script, the Apple Maps app never opens at all! When I abort the script it *does* open, though. Any ideas for why this happens? Maybe I don't understand how the ImageFound() works yet.

Comment: Also, adding a wait between the Click and If statements doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I don't think there's a happy answer here. It appears the ImageFound() freezes the SUT as it searches the screen, and I need to define a very long wait (12 seconds) to give the SUT ample time to open the app so that when ImageFound() freezes the screen, the text could appear.

It still requires a different approach, though, because when the text "Allow" is **not** on the screen, it takes about 10 minutes to reach this conclusion. Looks like OCR may not be a great approach on app, because it only takes a few seconds to determine than an image isn't present.

Unfortunate that OCR is so slow in this context, because it's so useful for cross-platform scripts, but it's problematic in this instance.